# Data Access Layer in ASP.NET, best practices for making connections

Tags: c#, asp.net

Which is considered a better practice when creating a data access layer for use in ASP.NET/Web Services:

1) Open and close a connection within each method that retrieves data from the database;

2) Have a 'connection class' that deals with connecting to the database, and other separate classes that uses the connection class, by opening the connection in the constructor, and then closing the connection in the destructor.

(I tried to enter pseudo-code as an example, but stackexchange won't accept it. Sorry for no example.)

I'm concerned that the first method is going to open a million unnecessary connections to the database over time.  Or does ASP.NET just cache the connection and I don't have to worry about it?

Are there disadvantages or dangers about going about it the second method, which I guess would keep a connection a bit longer to the database?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with having a global connection class is that multiple web handlers would be calling it simultaneously. Sometimes you can have database objects with a lifetime and visibility scoped to that connection. (For example, a temporary table). If you have multiple simultaneous queries running on that same connection, then these queries might inadvertently interfere with one another.

What you want is a *Pool* of connections. Here, there are a number of connections kept open, but when a function accesses a connection it has exclusive usage of it.

If you are using SQL Server, then this is provided for you for free:

[SQL Server Connection Pooling (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx)